# SharePoint REST query SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager special characters

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

This question is an extension of this one I found as a starting point (which works without special characters):
[SharePoint REST query SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340299/sharepoint-rest-query-sp-userprofiles-peoplemanager)

Basically the problem I am having is the query does not accurately respond to `accountName` with special characters. Specifically, a `'` in the last name for this example. The query either returns no results or is a 400 Bad Request.

In the code example I have used `encodeURIComponent()`, but I have also tried `escape()` and string escapes `"\"`.

At this point I am assuming its a bug on the MS side, but I cannot find any support documentation, nor any examples of code that have done this successfully.

```
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
var accountName = "Domain\\LoginFirstName_O'AccountLastName";
$.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='" + encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "'",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {

             console.log(data);     

    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

Comment: Try this: "Domain\\\\LoginFirstName_O'AccountLastName"; Yup - 4 backslashes.

Comment: @Sandesire Tried it, no dice.  Again, I am pretty sure the problem is coming from the ', not the \'s.

Comment: What happens when you try with a "normal" name?

Comment: @Sandesire With 2 slashes, works fine (as I mentioned at the top), with 4, 400 error

Comment: Ok, try again with encodeURI instead of encodeURIComponent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I was closer to the answer than I thought, but I overlooked it.  Basically, SharePoint's way of escaping worked in this case.  I needed to add code to replace the single `'` with `''`.

I also found that the request encodes it regardless of the `encodeURIComponent()`, so for this one I opted to remove it. Up to you if you want to use it or not.

Here is my final code snippet:

```
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
var accountName = "Domain\\LoginFirstName_O'AccountLastName";
accountName = accountName.replace("'","''");

$.ajax({
url: siteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='" + accountName + "'",
method: "GET",
headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
success: function (data) {

         console.log(data);     

},
error: function (data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}
});
```