# SharePoint REST API: Getting error "serverRelativeUrl" is missing or invalid while trying to move a file having special character '

Tags: python, sharepoint

I am using SharePoint REST API with python to move a file using the below URL

```
move_url = app_site + "/sites/" + sitename + "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl(@SrcFile)/moveto(newurl=@DestFile,flags=1)?@SrcFile=" + src_file_to_dwnld + "&@DestFile=" + dest_file_to_downld + ""
```

The filename has a `'` character in the name .e.g `example Dec'd.pdf`.

I am always getting a response with the error message saying `The query string "serverRelativeUrl" is missing or invalid`

I came across [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee540274(v%3Doffice.14)) site where it says

> It must not contain the following illegal characters: [!#$&'+:<>?\{|}~]|(//)|(..)|(/_)|(/wpresources$)|(/wpresources/)

I tried to follow the solution provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793930/sharepoint-rest-query-sp-userprofiles-peoplemanager-special-characters) question to escape the character by using `''` but getting a `404` file not found error.

Is there anything am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this issue on my **SPO** library and it works well if i replace quote with double quote.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is working, there was a problem while creating the URL causing this to failed. After you confirmed I doubled checked it and now it is working. Thanks for your help.